# Create events Facebook Open Graph

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this Graph API Explorer and I write https://graph.facebook.com/me/events, method "POST". Additionally I have the token and all permissions.

When I clik "DONE" I have the following error:

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Invalid parameter", 
    "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}

Can you help me?